# Ionic Push Notification not even sent to iOS (let alone received) on production

Tags: ios, macos, ionic-framework, push-notification, certificate

I have an issue with Push Notification for iOS in production mode.

I first developed Push for development:

- created dev provisioning profile on Mac
- created dev certificate on Mac
- created a dev security profile in Ionic Dashboard
- added dev certificate to dev security profile Ionic dashboard

All worked fine for Android as well as iOS.

I then switched to production:

- created provisioning profile and certificate for live on Mac
- created a live security profile in Ionic Dashboard and added live certificate

I always test Push using Postman:

send *POST* to `https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications` with body:

```
{
    "tokens": [
        "<ios token>",
        "<android token>"
    ],
    "profile": "live",
    "notification": {
        "message": "test",
        "ios": {
            "priority": 10
        },
        "android": {
            "priority": "high"
        }
    }
}
```

response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "status": "open",
    "config": {
      "profile": "live",
      "notification": {
        "android": {
          "priority": "high"
        },
        "ios": {
          "priority": 10
        },
        "message": "test"
      },
      "tokens": [
        "<ios token>",
        "<android token>"
      ]
    },
    "created": "2017-02-14T15:07:58.988762+00:00",
    "app_id": "<app id>",
    "uuid": "<uuid>",
    "state": "enqueued"
  },
  "meta": {
    "status": 201,
    "request_id": "<request id>",
    "version": "2.0.0-beta.0"
  }
}
```

To see what's going on, I always send a *GET* afterwards to `https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications/`‍**`<uuid>`**‍`/messages` *(`uuid`from the first response)* and get the following response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "status": "sent",
      "created": "2017-02-14T15:07:59.165266+00:00",
      "user_id": null,
      "token": {
        "token": "<android token>",
        "valid": true,
        "type": "android",
        "app_id": "<app id>",
        "invalidated": null,
        "id": "<id>",
        "created": "2017-02-14T14:27:27.585235+00:00"
      },
      "error": null,
      "notification": "<notification uuid>",
      "uuid": "<message uuid>"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "status": 200,
    "request_id": "<request id>",
    "version": "2.0.0-beta.0"
  }
}
```

I noticed that the data for the corresponding `<ios token>` is missing in the response.
I'm wondering why there isn't even an error response as listed at [Ionic Docs](http://legacy.docs.ionic.io/docs/push-error-codes).
If I send both requests using the **dev** security profile I get data for iOS stating "*error*" (`APNS_BAD_DEVICE_TOKEN`) - which is correct.

I already tried re-creating the certificate and stuff, which does not change the result. I also waited a whole day to receive a notification, in case something takes really long. I made double sure I built the app with the correct profiles in Xcode.

I'm using Xcode 8.2 by the way - and definetly made sure to enable "*Push Notifications*" in capabilities.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the Xcode version you are using?

Comment: @stackfan I'm using Xcode 8.2 and definetly made sure to enable Push at capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting the Ionic Support they brought up the idea to check for the tokens being valid.

The How-To is documented in [their docs](https://docs.ionic.io/api/endpoints/push.html#get-tokens-token_id):

`(GET) https://api.ionic.io/push/tokens/:token_id` (where `token_id` is a md5 hash of the device token)

I added a Pre-request Script in Postman for that like:

```
var token = "<your-device-token-to-check>";
var hash = CryptoJS.MD5( token ).toString();
postman.setEnvironmentVariable('token_hash', token);
```

... and added the new environment variale as a Parameter (not in the Request URL) as `key: (leave empty); value: ":{{token_hash}}"`

I then found out, that all my iOS tokens were invalidated shortly after they were registered. That's how our first tests succeeded and at further development suddenly failed.
I don't know why they are then left out on the response, when checking for notification status against the Ionic API. I suggested the Support to add an error response (as I understand it, there already is one: 'APNS_BAD_DEVICE_TOKEN' as "*The specified device token was bad. Verify that you specified a valid token* [...]".)

Because I cannot explain why, I just re-created new profiles and certificates (again!), and deleted the old ones from the Keychain Access on the Mac. I re-built the app and everything went fine. Weird...

Comment: I want to add, that I read somewhere to make sure to never mix up dev and live tokens when sending PNs to production APNS. Apple tends to invalidate all the tokens then. So I cleared up my database where I stored all registered devices (i.e. tokens) to send out PNs to.